# Is there any way to send Email notifications on timely bases in php

Tags: php, email

Actually my requirement is that, I have to send email after some (pre-defined) time interval (which is set by Admin through admin panel etc) like "After every week" or "every fortnight" or "every month" or "daily".

I have inserted all data i.e users email info etc and the time interval after which email notification is to be sent in Database.

Now I am required to run a script in cron job to send email notifications to users with their respective (repeating) time interval (set by admin and stored in DB). I am confused how to do so.

So can anyone kindly help me out to resolve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How and where are you keeping track of when the previous message was sent (or the entry was added, for new entries)?

Answer (score 2):

You can just create a regular PHP script that first gets the users and the interval from the database and then sends the e-mails. Then you should call this script on a time interval (for example every hour) and check whether it should execute (so whether the interval time has passed since the last execution time, which you should also store. Most hosts have information on how to set up cron jobs.

Comment: Correct! However, you can simply invoke the script once every 24 hours instead of every hour, since the maximum frequency you require is once a day.

Comment: But, I think, in the cron job we can set the time interval manually, but I need to send emails at the time interval set in the database, I think you understand what do I mean! or please explain in more detail because I might have not understood your answer.

Comment: @Gaurav Gupta: Yes, I agree. I decided to go for every hour because I thought it were just examples and once every hour should also be possible.

Comment: @swdeveloper: The PHP script you call in the cron job is just a regular PHP script: you can do everything you can also do in other scripts. This means you can connect to the database to get the needed interval, and when the interval is longer than the difference of the current time and the last-send time (which you have also saved in for example a database), you also get all e-mail addresses from the database. Then you send the e-mails, and when that is finished you set the last-send time again in the database. Has this helped?

Comment: Hi all thanks a lot for your support and advices. Actually I solved my problem by making 3 different files each for sending emails daily, weekly and monthly respectively and added those 3 files in the CRON job separately with setting (interval) of 1 Day, 1 Week and 1 Month respectively, i.e. in a file that sends emails daily, I wrote the code to fetch those users emails where time interval was set (by admin etc) "1 Day" and then added that file in cron job with an interval of 1 day and so on for weekly and monthly. And in this way I got a solution.